# Is the B+ model strong enough to play Vob files on OpenElec?

Tags: openelec

So I have installed OpenElec on my Raspberry Pi B+ and everything is working smoothly, except for playing DVD format files. When I press play on a video_ts.ifo it plays, but it plays shakey. The sound seems a-okay, but the visuals look laggy and shakey. So im not sure what the problem is. Is the B+ not strong enough to decode on the fly and should I overclock or upgrade to the Pi 2? Or is something else going on?

Edit: I just checked and the cpu0 seemed to be at 100% while playing the DVD file. So would I be able to tweak the raspberry pi to play such files by overclocking or something? Or would that still not be enough?

Comment: You can overclock but generally it isn't enough (depending on the exact files) - grab an RPI2

Comment: Well we don't have any problems with regular 1080p mkv files, so we'll just stick to those and re-download the DVD formatted movies. Too bad though.

Answer (score 1):

The B+ model should be strong enough to play DVD files. The problem is that OpenElec can't decode MPEG-2 video in hardware. It has to decode the movie software wise, which is going too slow to be able to play the movie smoothly.

So to play such files smoothly you need to [purchase the mpeg-2 license key](http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/) from the raspberry pi store or reformat the movies to any other popular format.

[Here](http://thedigitallifestyle.com/w/index.php/2012/08/29/what-do-the-mpeg-2-and-vc-1-decoder-options-get-you-on-the-raspberry-pi/) is more information on what you can natively play and what you need a certain codec for. Basically you need the MPEG-2 license key to play WTV SD, WTV HD and DVD formatted files. On the other hand, you need the VC-1 license key to play WMV files.